# How to style Owl Carousel navigation buttons (Previous or next)

Tags: html, css, web

I want to add small square button instead of oval shaped navigation button in owl carousel.

kindly help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5):

stylization of the navigation buttons is happening in owl.theme.css

```
/* Styling Next and Prev buttons */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #869791;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);/*IE7 fix*/
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```